# Qt widgets custom QMainWindow title bar

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have removed original title bar with `Qt::FramelessWindowHint`. I'm trying to re-implement it now. I have created a widget and I would like to put it above menuBar but it allows me to put widgets only inside centralWidget. What's the best way to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: You cannot replace the TitleBar. However, you can implement a class inherited from QMenuBar which add a title and then add the MenuBar. As the QMenuBar class inherit from QWidget that can be done.

Comment: I would like to have completely custom title bar, with custom background and own close, minimize buttons to match my dark theme. There must be easier way...

Comment: @GabrieldeGrimouard other question, how can I dock my widget to the top of the QMainWindow, so it looks like a title bar.

Comment: With QMainWindow.setMenuBar(QMenuBar*). There is nothing in QMainWindow which can be set above the MenuBar (except if you want to recreate a part of the QMainWindow). So no there is no simpler way (I can think of for now) that is easier than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a widget with a `QVBoxLayout`, in which as first element you insert your custom title bar that will appear on the top, and as second element the menubar widget. Then in the `QMainWindow` instance instead of using `setMenuBar` you can use `setMenuWidget` in order to put your widget in the menu bar position.